# How do I display attachments in column for Lists?

Tags: custom-list, task-list

I am using SharePoint 13. I am creating a Task List and a Custom List. I am attaching a resume as a Word file to the Task List and Custom List. Under Columns which type of column should I use to allow the team-member to see that the word document is attached? I was thinking of using Hyperlink or Picture. But perhaps there is a better option. By the way, I tried the Hyperlink or Picture but it's really not what I am looking for.

And what does "add to all content types" mean on the bottom of this option?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a multiple lines of text column. It allows you to create links (e.g. to a file in a document library).

Answer (score 1):

If you change the view of your list, you can enable the column "Attachments". A paperclip icon will show that the list item has an attachment.